# How i remove windows xp and install ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, windows-xp

I have an old pc intel P4 2.6GHz 1Gb ram 80GbHDD.I want to remove windows xp professional and install ubuntu(i downloaded ubuntu 12.04.1).If it is possible i would like you to show me what to do step by step.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somehow unclear. Would you like to keep all of your files in windows? If you want then, move the files to another drive. I would recommend you to backup all important files from ALL drives in case you mess it up.

Then try installing ubuntu.

I donot remember all the process but while there are choices, go for
"Install ubuntu"
"try something else"
Then on one of the drives(like `/dev/sda1`), there is winXP. Delete the drive. Then add a new partition of size ~2GB as SWAP and make it logical drive. Then again, make a new drive of remaining storage. Set the mount point to `/`. Processed from the screen. Done!